# Cubepoints: author Link and Ranks

Tags: wordpress

have been playing with Cubepoints (wordpress plugin) and have installed the ranks module but can't work out how I would add the persons ranks to the top user widget. I have ranks displaying in the authors profile but can't figure out what the shortcode would be and what I'd have to put in hooks file, anyone know?

On a related note I want to link to the authors profile page from the top user widget, but can't seem to find anything in the shortcode about this. Must be possible as I have seen blogs using this plugin doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the text field of the widget write:
`<a href="http://#/members/%user%">%username%</a>%points%`

This is for Buddypress. If you are using WordPress without this plugin, write this
`<a href="http://#/author/%user%">%username%</a>`